# Verify an Outlook Signature with Bouncy Castle Mail

Tags: java, email, outlook, bouncycastle, smime

I've written an Application to receive mails via IMAP from an Google account. I use https://github.com/markenwerk/java-utils-mail-smime which includes BCMail 1.5.6. I try to verify a mail which is sent from Outlook 2016. BCMail raises an exception: `message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value`. But verifying a mail from Thunderbird, which was signed with the same certificate works. Looking into the mails I spotted two differences: **Outlook** uses the protocol `application/x-pkcs7-signature` with micalg `SHA1` and **Thunderbird** the protocol `application/pkcs7-signature` with micalg `sha-256`. I already tested this solution: http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/CMS+and+SMIME+APIs but it doesn't work. 
Is there a known workaround or a general solution for signed Outlook (not only 2016) Mails?

Comment: This sounds somewhat complex. It had been a while since I worked with BouncyCastle (directly via JavaMail, not using any other library besides BC itself). So maybe(!) I can help you, but you could make it a little easier for me by sharing your own project on GitHub. It should ideally be a working Maven project and I would also need sample certificates and complete e-mail examples from both Thunderbird and Outlook so as to make the whole situation reproduceable.

Comment: Dear Daniel, it looks as though you need some help, why else post a question and put a bounty upon it? But if you do not answer follow-up questions it will be kind of hard to get meaningful answers. One whole week has passed without any reaction from you.